# Does Google Play Licensing require permission "android.permission.INTERNET"?

Tags: android, android-lvl

Does Google Play Licensing require permission "android.permission.INTERNET"?
My app does not require INTERNET permissions. Do I need to ask users for it if I want to use Google Play Licensing service?

Comment: any action that needs to be done using internet requires internet permission

Comment: not if they can get the data from the internet indirectly (like in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you will need to add licensing permission:
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/adding-licensing.html#manifest-permission

Answer (score 0):

No. Your app will make licensing requests via the Play app (as an intermediary), not direct to the Play servers. All the licensing calls are done like this:

YourApp <> PlayStoreApp <> Play Servers